# Why does my program run at drastically different speeds on different computers?

Tags: java, processor, conways-game-of-life, cpu-architecture

So I sent a friend a copy of my implementation of Conway's Game of Life. When he received it, he complained that my application [on the super-sampled grid size, with 0 delay] was barely getting **1 generation/second**. I responded that on my computer, with approximately the same amount of filled grid spaces, I was getting around **38 generations/second**. I couldn't attribute this disparity to different monitor sizes, as mine was more or less the same size, and the grids were therefore similarly sized. I ran my program from the jar as well, for consistency's sake.

Here's the kicker: His computer is running an **AMD Phenom II X6 1090T processor @ 3.2 Ghz (6-cores)**, with eight GB of RAM. My computer is running **i7-4700MQ @ 2.4 Ghz (quad-core)**, and 8 GB of RAM. He also has an Nvidia Ge-Force GT 440, vs. my intel integrated graphics.

It is beyond me how my computer can so profoundly outperform his, despite being inferior in every statistic. *Does anyone know what could cause this?* I am guessing it's something to do with the differences in processor architecture, but I'm no expert. Below is a link to the GitHub page for my project, in case you want to compile and test it yourself.

https://github.com/JoeAzar/CGOL-v1.3.2/tree/master

Comment: It might be interesting to compare the JVM version on the two machines as well.

Comment: There are any number of reasons this could be the case. Processor architecture is not likely to be it.

Comment: the github project does not compile. Even after fixing file names, it requires absent package `GraphingIV`.

Comment: @Alexei Sorry about that, I accidentally left some imports in there. Should work now.

Comment: @Dave What makes you say that?

Comment: @Azar Because there's nothing in your GoL implementation (or most any other) that would stress architectural-level design issues. Unrelated, but when making a project for others to use: 1) use normal Java conventions, 2) use normal Java source file naming conventions, 3) provide a build file.

Comment: @Dave Sorry Dave, I really only made the GitHub post so that others could see exactly what you've pointed out "nothing in your GoL implementation (or most any other) that would stress architectural-level design issues." I hadn't intended on "making a project for others to use."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does anyone know what could cause this? I am guessing it's something to do with the differences in processor architecture, but I'm no expert.

Well I'm only guessing too, but it could be things like:

- Different operating systems
- Different versions / releases of Java
- 32 bit versus 64 bit issues, at the JVM or OS level.
- Different JVM parameters; e.g. those that affect heap size.
- Differences in paging disk speed / latency (if the application is paging).
- Other stuff running on the machine (e.g. resource hogging AV software)

It could also be processor architecture related ... as you postulated ... though I'd put that well down the list of possible reasons.

Comment: Well, he had Windows 7, and I had 8. Same Java versions, both 64 bit. As for the rest I can't say. I suppose it's really just too hard to find a specific cause, given the amount of variables.